# Selection sort 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

What is the algorithm for a selection sort for a two dimensional array? I've looked and read up about 2D arrays everywhere, but I can't find anything that is simple and direct, so I've resorted to asking on a forum. (I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to change the sort of a 1D array to make it a 2D array!!)

For example, this:

```
name ----- crime ----- year

name1 ---- arson ----- 1996
name2 ---- theft ----- 2003
name3 ---- arson ----- 1976
name4 ---- theft ----- 2010
```

Becomes this:

```
name ----- crime ----- year

name1 ---- arson ----- 1996
name3 ---- arson ----- 1976
name2 ---- theft ----- 2003
name4 ---- theft ----- 2010
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

## EDIT

Here is the code I have for the selection sort. Most of them are organized properly, but in a couple of lines, I have "arson" where it doesn't belong and I'm not sure why that is. Here is my code:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        smallest = i;
        for(j = i; j < 10; j++){
            if(criminals[i][1].compareTo(criminals[j][1]) > 0){
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        temp = criminals[i][1];
        criminals[i][1] = criminals[smallest][1];
        criminals[smallest][1] = temp;
    }

    //output
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println(criminals[i][0] + " - " + criminals[i][1] + " - " + criminals [i][2]);
    }
```

And this is my input and output:

```
Not sorted list:
Al Capone - arson - 2009
Slippery Sal - theft - 2001
Nada - arson - 1987
Slippery Sal - theft - 1999
Salma - assault - 2010
Scooby Doo - theft - 1998
Velma - assault - 1991
Daphne - arson - 1976
Fred - assault - 2003
Shaggy - arson - 2007
Sorted list (by crime):
Al Capone - arson - 2009
Slippery Sal - arson - 2001
Nada - arson - 1987
Slippery Sal - assault - 1999
Salma - arson - 2010
Scooby Doo - assault - 1998
Velma - assault - 1991
Daphne - theft - 1976
Fred - theft - 2003
Shaggy - theft - 2007
```

Comment: Convert the array to a 1D array, sort that, and put the results back into the 2D array.

Comment: What do you mean by sorting a 2D array?  In many languages, a 2D array is just a 1D array of arrays, and arrays are often comparable.  Or are you thinking that the 2D array is a sequence of values just written in rows?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @RayToal It is an array of arrays. I had to write a list of criminals (10 rows), and for each criminal I had to have a name, crime, year (3 columns). I want to sort the list by crimes and I have to use a selection sort, but I want the name of the criminal and year to stay with the crime.

Comment: @RayToal See  http://jade-cheng.com/hpu/2012-spring/csci-2912/2d-arrays-sorting-and-binary-search/#selection-sort

Comment: It would be better to create class `Criminal` (with all related information), unless it's a school exercise on `2D` arrays.

Comment: @PM77-1  that algorithm sorts a 1D array of strings.  The OP is asking about 2D arrays.

Comment: @PM77-1 It's a school exercise, unfortunately. Any advice?

Comment: You said it yourself:  ***It is an array of arrays*** So, create a method for sorting `1D` arrays and run it for each element (which is array itself.

Comment: All you need to know is how to declare 2d array, how to access the elements, which are arrays, and the elements you sort by in those arrays, and how to move around the rows that you are sorting.

Comment: A quick look at your sample input and output shows that your output lines are not the same as your input lines.  In fact what you see is that only the middle column values have moved while the first and last have changed positions.  Make sure when you swap you swap entire rows, not just the values in column 1.  So use the values in column 1 for comparing, but then swap entire rows.

Answer (score 3):

For your criminal thing, do this:

```
static final int SORT_BY_NAME = 0;
static final int SORT_BY_CRIME = 1;
static final int SORT_BY_YEAR = 2;
```

Assuming this :

```
Object[10][3] = {{"Name", "CRIME", "YEAR"},...};
```

Now to your sort algorithm:

```
void SelSort(Objects[][] criminals, int sortBy) 
{
    if (criminals == NULL || criminals.length == 0 || sortBy >= criminals[0].length || sortBy < 0)
        return;

    int i,j;
    Object min;

    for (i=0; i < criminals.length ; i++) {
       min = criminals[i][sortBy];
        for (j = i+1; j < criminals.length; j++){
            if (((criminals[j][sortBy].getClass()).cast(min)).compareTo(criminals[j][sortBy]) == 1){//Assuming you can compare them this way else make a method to compare
                Object tmp = criminals[j];
                criminals[j] = criminals[i];
                criminals[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }             

}
```

Comment: This was helpful! What are k and l, exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an incorrect interpretation of OP's question. @RayToal has the right idea.

Comment: What i was doing, was traversing each element of the matrix, k and l where the indexs to traverse the whole matrix (2D array) to find the minimum. What i was doing, in small words, is think of the matrix(2D array) as 1 big 1D array and traverse it. Like 2x10 matrix has the following members:  [a00 a01 a02 ... a09 -> a10 a11 a 12....a19]

Now, k and l would let me, for each of those elements(lets say i was holding the current position in the matrix with i and j, to traverse the remaining elements to find the minimum and swap it.

Comment: This is correct. Although you might want to use lowercase for variable name (so it's `criminals`, not `Criminals`) and you can use `obj.compareTo(obj1) == 1` instead of using `obj > obj1`

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, to be picky, it looks like you have an array of `Criminal` objects, something like

```
class Criminal {
    private String name;
    private String crime;
    private int year;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then you would have a 1D array of criminal objects.  You can use the regular selection sort algorithm, but instead of comparing

```
criminals[i] < criminals[j]
```

you would compare

```
criminals[i].getCrime() < criminals[j].getCrime()
```

Now, let's be not picky and assume that you really do have a 2-D array of strings, so each row of the array is itself an array of strings.  Then just do the selection sort but compare like this:

```
criminals[i][1] < criminals[j][1]
```

This works because

```
criminals[row][0]   is the name
criminals[row][1]   is the crime
criminals[row][2]   is the year
```

When you do the swap, entire rows will be swapped, and you'll have what you want.

Comment: This has been already discussed in comments. OP is doing school assignment on `2D` arrays.

Comment: True, but as a school assignment I think the OP is stuck with having to use the 2D arrays for which the `[1]` is likely to help.  If someone else chimes in and finds this answer of no value beyond what is said in the comments, I'll happily delete it.

Comment: I used this and it worked! Except for one thing. One of the outputs is off. Most are organized perfectly, but then I have a random "arson" midst a bunch of "assault" listed crimes. I'll post my code.

Comment: Thanks.  And here is the patched code that now works: http://ideone.com/hwdzll    Please note to make it run on ideone, I had to change the name of the class to `Main` and remove the prompts and just read directly from standard input.  You can of course patch it back up.  I think you should be able to find the changes I made to the algorithm to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, the specified overall sort criteria is that: within each row, the elements must be sorted.

Run the [Selection sort](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap10/subsection2.1.2.1.html)  algorithm on each 1D array( of the 2D array) at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Hence, your 2D array is `String[][] array`. Then initialize array and do the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        if (array[j][sortByColIndex].compareTo(array[index][sortByColIndex]) < 0)
        {
            index = j;
        }
    }
    String smallerNumber = scores[index][sortByColIndex];
    scores[index][sortByColIndex] = scores[i][sortByColIndex];
    scores[i][sortByColIndex] = smallerNumber;

    // Displaying sorted value
    System.out.print(array[i][0] + "\t" + array[i][1] + "\t" + array[i][2] + "\t");

}
```